# SQL Server: how to add case statement to select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement, case

I am using the following select to query a date from a database table.

The input (ms) for this query results from an xml string and the stored procedure then loops through all the single values in the xml to return a certain number (integer) for each of them. 
This works fine so far.

Is there a way that I can return a placeholder number (like 99999) if the input (ms) is empty / nothing ? 
Currently the below returns 0 in such a case which I cannot use to identify this as 0 can also be a valid result in other cases.

**My stored procedure so far:**

```
SELECT ms as date,
    type, 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(calendar_dt)
        FROM        Calendar
        WHERE       day_of_week NOT IN (1, 7)
        AND         calendar_dt > GETDATE()
        AND         calendar_dt <= ms
    ) as bDays
FROM @dates
FOR XML PATH('ms'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column "ms" is actually NULL or populated, just use ISNULL.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx

`SELECT ISNULL(ms, 99999) AS date`

However, if that column can contain an empty string, which is not the same as NULL, then also use NULLIF.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx

`SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(ms,''), 99999) AS date`

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes, it can contain an empty string but I cannot add this to my select above as it causes an error saying I can only have one element in my select list.

Comment: Ok, I can add this, just had a typo before - sorry for that. ms is defined as datetime so it creates a date out of the 99999 making it 2173-10-15T00:00:00. Is there a way to avoid this so that i can keep the value ?

Comment: Data type is as data type does. You should set a default that is of the same datatype. But you can try to CAST or CONVERT the value to a string.

Comment: It turned out your suggestion to use ISNULL / NULLIF is the perfect solution and works great for what I need, just had to adapt some parts of my code a little. Thanks again !